# how to insert bit datatype column value

Tags: vb.net

I have a drop down list box,It content 'Yes' and 'No'.
I insert this value into the database table data type of column is a bit how can I insert this value into vb.net

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO application_main(obligations_is) VALUES( '" + convertBit(dropdownlist1.text) + "' )"

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

      Public Function convertBit(ByVal dropdownlist As String)
    Dim value As Integer


    If dropdownlist = "Yes" Then
        value = 1
    Else
        value = 0
    End If

    Return value
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function while inserting BIT Columns

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO application_main(obligations_is) VALUES( ISNULL('" + convetbit() + "',0) )"

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

And fucnction should be like this

```
Public Function convertBit(ByVal dropdownlist As String) AS Boolean
    Dim value As Boolean = Flase
    If dropdownlist = "Yes" Then
        value = 1
    Else
        value = 0
    End If
        Return value
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO application_main(obligations_is) VALUES(@value)"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", If ((dropdownlist1.text = "Yes"), True, False))
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```